# How can I calculate the difference between two dates in Luxon?

Tags: reactjs, luxon

I'm doing a project in React js and I need calculate the difference between dates.
The first one the user choose the startTime(state) and the endTime(state) and the program give the differecen in years, months and days ( this program is done and working).
Now I'm trying calculate the difference in days between the day 1-01-2022 and other date that the user choose.
I have tryed change the format but I receive errors.

```
    //this is working
const date1 = DateTime.fromISO(endTime.toISOString());
const date2 = DateTime.fromISO(startTime.toISOString());
let durationDate =  date1.diff(date2, ["years", "months", "days"]);
//--------------

//this is not working
const date3 = DateTime.fromISO(endTime.toISOString());
const dateNow = DateTime.now().startOf("year").toISO();
let dateTermination = endTime.diff(dateNow,  ["years", "months", "days"]).toObject();
```

//----------------

Comment: This isn't working because `toISO()` returns a string, and you're using it as a Luxon DateTime